# message queue in C: implementing 2 way comm

Tags: c, linux, pointers, ipc, message-queue

I am a student and a begineer in C. I want to implement 2 way communication using message queue in C linux. Do I need two queues or only one to get this done?

Also I would like to know can I send data(shown in code) to another process or i need to declare it as a character array.

```
typedef struct msg1
{
    int mlen;
    char *data;
}M1;

typedef struct msgbuf
{
    long    mtype;
    M1      *m;
} message_buf;
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you want to send messages between processes, read more about [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipc), and use something like [POSIX message queues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipc), because you can't do it by just sending e.g. pointers between processes (as each process has its own private memory map).

Comment: And yes, for two-way communication you need two queues.

Comment: you will need multiple message queues. Trying to use a single message queue for two-way communication between multiple processes would turn into a complex situation

Comment: @Jayesh I just wanted to know if its possible? Is it?

Comment: Well, if you only want a synchronous ACK, you could maybe store a handle to an inter-process synchro object in the message, upon which the issuing process will wait The receiving process could load the message up with the ACK data and then signal the synchro object?

Comment: Oh - may need DuplicateHandle(), at least on Windows, to get a handle to the event/semaphore/whatever that the target process can signal.

Answer (score 6):

> Also I would like to know can I send data(shown in code) to another process or i need to declare it as a character array

yes you can send data to another process

like

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXSIZE     128

void die(char *s)
{
  perror(s);
  exit(1);
}

struct msgbuf
{
    long    mtype;
    char    mtext[MAXSIZE];
};

main()
{
    int msqid;
    int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
    key_t key;
    struct msgbuf sbuf;
    size_t buflen;

    key = 1234;

    if ((msqid = msgget(key, msgflg )) < 0)   //Get the message queue ID for the given key
      die("msgget");

    //Message Type
    sbuf.mtype = 1;

    printf("Enter a message to add to message queue : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]",sbuf.mtext);
    getchar();

    buflen = strlen(sbuf.mtext) + 1 ;

    if (msgsnd(msqid, &sbuf, buflen, IPC_NOWAIT) < 0)
    {
        printf ("%d, %d, %s, %d\n", msqid, sbuf.mtype, sbuf.mtext, buflen);
        die("msgsnd");
    }

    else
        printf("Message Sent\n");

    exit(0);
}


//IPC_msgq_rcv.c

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXSIZE     128

void die(char *s)
{
  perror(s);
  exit(1);
}

typedef struct msgbuf
{
    long    mtype;
    char    mtext[MAXSIZE];
} ;


main()
{
    int msqid;
    key_t key;
    struct msgbuf rcvbuffer;

    key = 1234;

    if ((msqid = msgget(key, 0666)) < 0)
      die("msgget()");


     //Receive an answer of message type 1.
    if (msgrcv(msqid, &rcvbuffer, MAXSIZE, 1, 0) < 0)
      die("msgrcv");

    printf("%s\n", rcvbuffer.mtext);
    exit(0);
}
```

If you know about message queue, then Message Queue is used for inter-process communication.

Also for two-way communication between multiple processes you need multiple message queue

Comment: two way comm between given two processes only, requires how many queues atleast??

Comment: two message queue required

Comment: @user3433848, you can do two-way communication with a sysv MQ but it requires a level of familiarity with queues you have yet to attain and, even under the best of circumstances, is a questionable practice unless you are really forced into it by circumstances.  Two queues are easier all the way around.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a message queue I wrote that I can include in any of my multi-threaded programs.  Between processes, you could use sockets, or mqueue.h, but this light-weight message queue library I designed works wonders.

Here is the "messaging.h" header file.

```
//  messaging.h
//
//  Created by Justin Jack on 11/2/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Justin Jack. All rights reserved.

// This code may be freely distributed for personal and business
// use.  Additional credits may be added, but the original author
// information musy stay part of this code.
//

#ifndef messaging_h
#define messaging_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAX_JMESSAGES 2000
#define JMSG_INIT_QUEUE_SIZE 100
#define JMSG_EMPTY_QUEUE -1

//#define QUEUE_DEBUG

static pthread_mutex_t messagelock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;




typedef enum _jmessages {
    JMSG_QUIT = 1,  // 1 
    JMSG_CHANGE,    // 2
    JMSG_FAILURE,   // 3
    JMSG_CONTINUE,  // 4
    JMSG_DRAW,      // 5
    JMSG_CUSTOM1,   // 6
    JMSG_CUSTOM2,   // 7
    JMSG_CUSTOM3,   // 8
    MSG_CUSTOM4,   // 9
    JMSG_CUSTOM5,   // 10
    JMSG_CUSTOM6,   // 11
    JMSG_CUSTOM7,   // 12
    JMSG_CUSTOM8,   // 13
    JMSG_CUSTOM9,   // 14
    JMSG_CUSTOM10  // 15
} JMESSAGES;



/* Returned by popmessage() */
typedef enum jmsg_returns {
    JMSG_NOMESSAGE, // 0
    JMSG_MOREMESSAGES, // 1
    JMSG_LASTMESSAGE, // 2
    JMSG_TIMEOUT // 3
} JMSG_RETURN;

typedef enum jmsg_errors {
    JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND = -1,
    JMSG_OKAY, // 0
    JMSG_QUEUEFULL, // 1
    JMSG_OUTOFMEMORY // 2
} JMSG_ERROR;

typedef struct jmessage {
   unsigned long long message;
    unsigned long long value1;
    unsigned long long value2;    
    union _mptr {
        void *voidptr;
        char *charptr;
        unsigned int *uintptr;
        int *intptr;
        double *doubleptr;
        float *floatptr;
        unsigned long long *lluptr;
        long long *llptr;
        short *shortptr;
        unsigned short *ushortptr;
    } ptr;
    int pointerlength;
    int needtofreepointer;
    pthread_t fromthread;
    const char *fromthreadname;
} JMESSAGE;

typedef struct jqueue {
    pthread_t owningthreadid;
    char semname[20];
    char threadname[100];
    sem_t *messagesignal;
    int queuesize;
    JMESSAGE *jmessagelist;
    int lastfulljmessage;
    struct jqueue *next;
    struct jqueue *previous;
} JQUEUE;

static JQUEUE *jqueue = 0;


/* Creates a messagequeue for the current thread */
int createmessagequeue( char *description );

/* Destroys the message queue on this thread */
int destroymessagequeue();

/* Sends the message in JMESSAGE *jmsg to another thread */
int pushmessage( JMESSAGE *jmsg, pthread_t to_thread_id );

/* Checks for a message waiting for this queue.  If found,
   it populates the message in the JMESSAGE * parameter passed.

   Returns:
   --------
   JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND (No call to createmessagequeue()
   JMSG_EMPTY_QUEUE   (The message queue was empty)
   JMSG_MOREMESSAGES  (You should loop while you get this)
   JMSG_LASTMESSAGE   (The last message on the stack)
 */
int popmessage( JMESSAGE *jmsg );

/* A blocking version of popmessage() */
int waitmessage( JMESSAGE *jmsg );

/* Internal Functions, public use not needed */
static int lockit();
static int unlockit();
static int popmessagenosem( JMESSAGE *jmsg );

#endif /* messaging_h */
```

And here is the "messaging.c" source file:

```
//
//  messaging.c
//  DeedleCore
//
//  Created by Justin Jack on 11/2/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Justin Jack. All rights reserved.
//

#include "messaging.h"


static int lockit() {
    int x= 0;
    pthread_t callingthreadid = pthread_self();
    x = pthread_mutex_lock(&messagelock);
#ifdef QUEUE_DEBUG
    if (x != 0 ) {
        printf("lockit(%lld) failed to lock mutex.\n", callingthreadid);
        switch (x) {
            case EINVAL:
                printf("\t\tEINVAL:The mutex was created with the protocol attribute having the value PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT and the calling thread's priority is higher than the mutex's current priority ceiling.\n");
                break;
            case EBUSY:
                printf("\t\tEBUSY:The mutex could not be acquired because it was already locked.\n");
                break;
            case EAGAIN:
                printf("\t\tEAGAIN:The mutex could not be acquired because the maximum number of recursive locks for mutex has been exceeded.\n");
                break;
            case EDEADLK:
                printf("\t\tEDEADLK:The current thread already owns the mutex.\n");
                break;
            case EPERM:
                printf("\t\tEPERM:The current thread does not own the mutex.\n");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
#endif
    return x;
}

static int unlockit() {
    int x = 0;
    pthread_t callingthreadid = pthread_self();
    x = pthread_mutex_unlock(&messagelock);
#ifdef QUEUE_DEBUG
    if (x) {
        printf("\tunlockit(&lld) failed to unlock mutex.\n", callingthreadid);
    }
#endif
    return x;
}

static char *getthreadname( pthread_t idnum ) {
    static char retval[] = "";
    JQUEUE *jq = jqueue;
    if (!jq) return retval;
    lockit();
    do {
        if (jq->owningthreadid == idnum) {
            unlockit();
            return jq->threadname;
        }
        jq = jq->next;
    } while (jq);

    unlockit();
    return retval;
}

int createmessagequeue( char *description ) {
    int retval = JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND;
    JQUEUE *jq = jqueue;
    pthread_t callingthreadid = pthread_self();

    pthread_mutexattr_t ptt;
    if (!jq) {
#ifdef QUEUE_DEBUG
        printf("messaging.c > Initializing Messaging System ********************** \n");
#endif
        pthread_mutexattr_init(&ptt);
#ifdef PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP
        pthread_mutexattr_settype(&ptt, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE_NP);
#else
        pthread_mutexattr_settype(&ptt, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
#endif
        pthread_mutex_init(&messagelock, &ptt);
        lockit();
        jqueue = calloc(1, sizeof(JQUEUE));
        if (jqueue) {
            jqueue->jmessagelist = calloc(JMSG_INIT_QUEUE_SIZE, sizeof(JMESSAGE));
            if (jqueue->jmessagelist) {
                jqueue->queuesize = JMSG_INIT_QUEUE_SIZE;
                jqueue->owningthreadid = callingthreadid;
                jqueue->lastfulljmessage = JMSG_EMPTY_QUEUE;
                if (description) {
                    if (strlen(description) < 100) {
                        sprintf(jqueue->threadname, "%s", description);
                    } else {
                        sprintf(jqueue->threadname, "%.*s", 99, description);
                    }
                }
                sprintf(jqueue->semname, "SEM%d", (int)callingthreadid);
                jqueue->messagesignal = sem_open(jqueue->semname, O_CREAT, 0644, 0);
#ifdef QUEUE_DEBUG
                printf("messaging.c > Message queue set up for \"%s\" (%lld).\n ", jqueue->threadname, callingthreadid);
#endif
                retval = JMSG_OKAY;
            } else {
                free(jqueue);
                jqueue = 0;
                retval = JMSG_OUTOFMEMORY;
            }
        } else {
            retval = JMSG_OUTOFMEMORY;
        }
    } else {
        lockit();
        do {
            if (jq->owningthreadid == callingthreadid) {
                retval = JMSG_OKAY;
                break;
            }
            if (jq->next == 0) {
                jq->next = calloc(1, sizeof(JQUEUE));
                if (jq->next) {

                    jq->next->jmessagelist = calloc(JMSG_INIT_QUEUE_SIZE, sizeof(JMESSAGE));

                    if (jq->next->jmessagelist) {
                        jq->next->previous = jq;
                        jq->next->queuesize = JMSG_INIT_QUEUE_SIZE;
                        jq->next->owningthreadid = callingthreadid;
                        jq->next->lastfulljmessage = JMSG_EMPTY_QUEUE;
                        sprintf(jq->next->semname, "SEM%d", (int)callingthreadid);
                        if (description) {
                            if (strlen(description) < 100) {
                                sprintf(jq->next->threadname, "%s", description);
                            } else {
                                sprintf(jq->next->threadname, "%.*s", 99, description);
                            }
                        }
#ifdef QUEUE_DEBUG
                        printf("messaging.c > Message queue set up for \"%s\" (%lld).\n ", jq->next->threadname, callingthreadid);
#endif
                        jq->next->messagesignal = sem_open(jq->next->semname, O_CREAT, S_IRWXU, 0);
                        retval = JMSG_OKAY;
                    } else {
                        free(jq);
                        jq = 0;
                        retval = JMSG_OUTOFMEMORY;
                    }
                }
                break;
            } 
            jq = jq->next;
        } while (jq);
    }
    unlockit();
    return retval;
}


int destroymessagequeue() {
    int i = 0, retval = JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND;
    JQUEUE *jq = jqueue;
    JMESSAGE *jm = 0;
    pthread_t callingthreadid = pthread_self();
    lockit();
    if (jq) {
        /* 
         * Search for messages waiting to be delivered that are from THIS
         * QUEUE that we're destroying.  We need to replace the pointer that
         * is pointing to the name of this queue with a generic (const char *)
         * saying "(dead queue)" so we don't get an invalid memory read when
         * it's delivered.
         * 
         */
        do {
            if (jq->owningthreadid != callingthreadid) {
                for (i = 0; i <= jq->lastfulljmessage; i++) {
                    jm = &jq->jmessagelist[i];
                    if (jm->fromthread == callingthreadid) {
                        jm->fromthreadname = "(dead queue)";
                    }
                }
            }
            jq = jq->next;
        } while (jq);


        /* Reset jq, find this queue and destroy it */
        jq = jqueue;
        do {
            if (jq->owningthreadid == callingthreadid) {
                /* Found the queue */
                retval = JMSG_OKAY;
#ifdef QUEUE_DEBUG
                printf("messaging.c > Destroying message queue for \"%s\" (%lld)\n", jq->threadname, jq->owningthreadid);
#endif
                /* 
                 Free any internal pointers that were supposed
                 to be freed after retrieval.
                 */
                for (i = 0; i <= jq->lastfulljmessage; i++) {
                    sem_wait(jq->messagesignal);
                    if (jq->jmessagelist[i].needtofreepointer) {
                        free(jq->jmessagelist[i].ptr.charptr);
                    }

                }
                /* Free the queue messages */
                free(jq->jmessagelist);

                sem_unlink(jq->semname);

                /* Unlink the queue */

                if (jq->previous) { /* If this isn't the first element */
                    jq->previous->next = jq->next;
                    if (jq->next) {
                        jq->next->previous = jq->previous;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (jq->next) {
                        jq->next->previous = 0;
                    }
                }

                free(jq);
                break;

            }
            jq = jq->next;
        } while (jq);
    }
    unlockit();
    return retval;
}

int pushmessage( JMESSAGE *jmsg, pthread_t to_thread_id ) {
    int queuespotsleft = 0, retval = JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND;
    JQUEUE *jq = jqueue;
    JMESSAGE *jm = 0, *newjmqueue;
    pthread_t callingthreadid = pthread_self();
    if (!jq) {
        return JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND;
    }
    lockit();
    do {
        if (jq->owningthreadid == to_thread_id) {
            if (jq->lastfulljmessage == JMSG_EMPTY_QUEUE) {
                jq->lastfulljmessage = 0;
                jm = &jq->jmessagelist[0];
            } else {
                if (jq->lastfulljmessage + 1 > MAX_JMESSAGES) {
                    /* We have too many messages backed up */
                    unlockit();
                    return JMSG_QUEUEFULL;
                }
                if (jq->lastfulljmessage + 1 > (jq->queuesize - 1)) {
                    /* 
                     * We're getting backed up, we need to allocate more
                     * space.  This is slowly moving the allocated message
                     * queue memory for this thread towards the MAX_JMESSAGES
                     * 
                     */
                    queuespotsleft = MAX_JMESSAGES - (jq->lastfulljmessage + 1);
                    if (queuespotsleft > 50) queuespotsleft = 50;
                    if (queuespotsleft > 0) {
                        newjmqueue = realloc(jq->jmessagelist, ((jq->lastfulljmessage + 1) * sizeof(JMESSAGE)));
                        if (!newjmqueue) {
                            unlockit();
                            return JMSG_OUTOFMEMORY;
                        }
                        jq->jmessagelist = newjmqueue;
                        jq->lastfulljmessage++;
                        jm = &jq->jmessagelist[jq->lastfulljmessage];
                    } else {
                        retval = JMSG_QUEUEFULL;
                    }
                } else {
                    /* It's withing the bounds of the allocated message space */
                    jm = &jq->jmessagelist[++jq->lastfulljmessage];
                }
            }
            if (jm) {
                retval = JMSG_OKAY;
                memcpy(jm, jmsg, sizeof(JMESSAGE));
                jm->fromthread = callingthreadid;
                jm->fromthreadname = getthreadname(callingthreadid);
                /* Go ahead and increment the semaphore count in case
                 * they're calling waitmessage()
                 * 
                 */
                sem_post(jq->messagesignal);
            }
            break;
        }
        jq = jq->next;
    } while (jq);
    unlockit();
    return retval;
}


int popmessage( JMESSAGE *jmsg ) {
    int retval = JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND;
    JQUEUE *jq = jqueue;
    pthread_t callingthreadid = pthread_self();
    if (!jq) {
        return JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND;
    }
    memset(jmsg, 0, sizeof(JMESSAGE));
    lockit();
    do {
        if (jq->owningthreadid == callingthreadid) {
            if (jq->lastfulljmessage > JMSG_EMPTY_QUEUE) {
                memcpy(jmsg, &jq->jmessagelist[jq->lastfulljmessage], sizeof(JMESSAGE));
                memset(&jq->jmessagelist[jq->lastfulljmessage], 0, sizeof(JMESSAGE));
                jq->lastfulljmessage--;
                retval = ((jq->lastfulljmessage == JMSG_EMPTY_QUEUE) ? JMSG_LASTMESSAGE : JMSG_MOREMESSAGES);
                /* Decrease the semaphore count because they're NOT calling waitmessage() but may later... */
                sem_wait(jq->messagesignal);
            } else {
                retval = JMSG_NOMESSAGE;
            }
            break;
        }
        jq = jq->next;
    } while (jq);
    unlockit();
    return retval;
}

/* 
 * This function is only called by waitmessage()  It doesn't decrease the
 * semaphore count, because we've already waited for it to be signaled 
 * in waitmessage().  This just pulls the message off of the stack.
 * 
 */
static int popmessagenosem( JMESSAGE *jmsg ) {
    int retval = JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND;
    JQUEUE *jq = jqueue;
    pthread_t callingthreadid = pthread_self();
    if (!jq) {
        return JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND;
    }
    lockit();
    do {
        if (jq->owningthreadid == callingthreadid) {
            if (jq->lastfulljmessage > JMSG_EMPTY_QUEUE) {
                memmove(jmsg, &jq->jmessagelist[jq->lastfulljmessage], sizeof(JMESSAGE));
                memset(&jq->jmessagelist[jq->lastfulljmessage], 0, sizeof(JMESSAGE));
                jq->lastfulljmessage--;
                retval = ((jq->lastfulljmessage == JMSG_EMPTY_QUEUE) ? JMSG_NOMESSAGE :
                ((jq->lastfulljmessage == 0) ? JMSG_LASTMESSAGE : JMSG_MOREMESSAGES));
            } else {
                retval = JMSG_NOMESSAGE;
            }
            break;
        }
        jq = jq->next;
    } while (jq);
    unlockit();
    return retval;
}



int waitmessage( JMESSAGE *jmsg ) {
    JQUEUE *jq = jqueue;
    sem_t *waitingon = 0;
    pthread_t callingthreadid = pthread_self();
    if (!jq) {
        return JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND;
    }
    lockit();
    do {
        if (jq->owningthreadid == callingthreadid) {
            //printf("Waiting on semaphore %s to be signalled...\n", jq->semname);
            waitingon = jq->messagesignal;
            break;
        }
        jq = jq->next;
    } while (jq);
    unlockit();
    if (!waitingon) return JMSG_QUEUENOTFOUND;
    //printf("waiting on semaphore!\n");
    sem_wait(waitingon);
    popmessagenosem(jmsg);
    //printf("semaphore signalled! continuing...\n");
    return JMSG_OKAY;
}
```

Enjoy! I love it.  I set up message loops in all my threads that do different things and data is easily and quickly conveyed!

And here is a working example using this code:
** BE SURE TO LINK TO -lpthread

```
#include <signal.h>
#include "messaging.h"

#define THREAD_STARTED      JMSG_CUSTOM1
#define THREAD_FAILED       JMSG_CUSTOM2
#define THREAD_EXITING      JMSG_CUSTOM3
#define THREAD_ACKNOWLEDGE  JMSG_CUSTOM4


void sighand( int signum ) {
    JMESSAGE msg;
    printf("\nSignal Received! Exiting...\n");
    msg.message = JMSG_QUIT;
    pushmessage(&msg, pthread_self()); /* Put this JMSG_QUIT message on 
                                        * the main thread's message queue 
                                        * to let the main code know to quit.
                                        */
    return;
}

void *mythread( void *_mainthreadid ) {
    pthread_t mainthreadid = (pthread_t)_mainthreadid;
    JMESSAGE msg;

    signal(SIGINT, &sighand); /* CTRL-C */

    if (!createmessagequeue("mythread")) {
        printf("main.c > mythread() > createmessagequeue(): Failed.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    /* 
     * Send a message to the main thread so it can do something when it 
     * knows we're ready.
     */
    msg.message = THREAD_ACKNOWLEDGE;
    pushmessage(&msg, mainthreadid);

    printf("main.c > mythread(): Launched successfully, using blocking message loop!\n");
    do {
        waitmessage(&msg); /* 
                            * Wait indefinitely.  You can, however, use a 
                            * signal to send a message to this queue to get
                            * it to move along, or signal it from another thread
                            * to get it to move along.  
                            * 
                            */
        switch (msg.message) {
            case THREAD_ACKNOWLEDGE:
                printf("main.c > mythread(): THREAD_ACKNOWLEDGE received from thread \"%s\" (0x%x).\n", msg.fromthreadname, msg.fromthread);
                fflush(stdout);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } while (msg.message != JMSG_QUIT);
    printf("main.c > mythread(): Got JMSG_QUIT.\n");
    msg.message = THREAD_EXITING;
    pushmessage(&msg, mainthreadid);
    printf("main.c > mythread(): Calling destroymessagequeue()!\n");
    destroymessagequeue();
    printf("main.c > mythread(): Exiting.\n");
    return 0;
}


int main( void ) {
    JMESSAGE msg;
    pthread_t mythreadid;
    int ret;

    ret = createmessagequeue("Main Thread");
    if (!ret) {
        printf("main.c > createmessagequeue(): Failed with %d.\n", ret);
        return 0;
    }

    pthread_create(&mythreadid, 0, &mythread, (void *)pthread_self());

    printf("main.c > main(): Press [CTRL-C] to terminate program.\n");
    do {
        /* NON Blocking message queue */
        if (popmessage(&msg)) {
            switch (msg.message) {
                case JMSG_QUIT:
                    /* Forward the message on to any other queues */
                    if (pushmessage(&msg, mythreadid)) {
                        printf("main.c > main(): Received JMSG_QUIT. Forwarded message to mythreadid\n");
                        fflush(stdout);
                        pthread_join(mythreadid, 0);
                    }
                    break;
                case THREAD_ACKNOWLEDGE:
                    printf("main.c > main(): Received a THREAD_ACKNOWLEDGE from thread \"%s\" (0x%x)\n", msg.fromthreadname, msg.fromthread);
                    /* Bounce message back for the heck of it */
                    pushmessage(&msg, mythreadid);
                    fflush(stdout);
                   break;
                case THREAD_EXITING:
                    printf("main.c > main(): Received a THREAD_EXITING from thread \"%s\" (0x%x)\n", msg.fromthreadname, msg.fromthread);
                    fflush(stdout);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else { /* No messages do some important stuff */
            usleep(20000); /* Take a breather */
        }
    } while (msg.message != JMSG_QUIT);
    printf("main.c > main(): Calling destroymessagequeue()!\n");
    destroymessagequeue();
    printf("main.c > main(): Exiting program!\n");
    fflush(stdout);
   return 0;
}
```